# The exact value of an infinite sum

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am unsure as to how to find the exact value of the following infinite sum:

> Find the exact value of the following infinite sum:
>
> $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{e^{n-2}}{5^{n-1}}$$

Comment: do you know about geometric series?

Answer (score 2):

It's just a geometric series with first term $\displaystyle \frac{e^{-2}}{5^{-1}} = \frac{5}{e^2}$ and common ratio $\displaystyle \frac{e}{5}$. Can you proceed from here?

Answer (score 0):

Its $\frac{a}{1-r}$ where $a$ is the first term and $r$ is the common ratio provided the sequence is in gp